# Getting the last element that starts-with a string (selenium)

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting some info from [this page](https://www.bandsintown.com/e/103227585-the-runaway-grooms-at-d.b.a.?came_from=253&utm_medium=web&utm_source=city_page&utm_campaign=event), and I'm trying to identify the last element that starts with the string "about".  In other words, trying to get : "About the Runaway Grooms".  I'm trying this code:

```
try:
    BioHeader= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(text(),'About')][last()]")
    print("Bio header: ", BioHeader.text)
except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
    pass
```

But it's giving me the first, not last instance.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

driver.find_element_by_xpath gives you just one element, the first one.

You need this, which generates a list of all instances.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
BioHeader = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(text(),'About')][last()]")
print("Bio header: ", BioHeader[1].text)
```

Comment: Thanks.  It seems to fail when there's only one "about" section, like in this page:  https://www.bandsintown.com/e/103097368-jimmy-eat-world-at-orpheum-theater?came_from=253&utm_medium=web&utm_source=city_page&utm_campaign=event

Comment: In this case, the code you provided just comes up blank.

Comment: Also, why do you need to index BioHeader[1] if the [last()] method is already returning just one instance (i.e. not a list?)

Answer (score 0):

Probably locator to be defined as below, can you please try as below

```
try:
    BioHeader= driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[starts-with(text(),'About')])[last()]")
    print("Bio header: ", BioHeader.text)
except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
    pass
```